# PHP reading my array of my shopping cart correctly?

Tags: php, arrays, webshop

I'm making a newbie webshop and I'm stuck on a problem. I've written a function to simply draw an item if it is defined. (so it will draw the image with its description, only if the item was actually added to my cart).

Note, this is obviously not the best way to do it. But it should work.

Setting my items. Will only work if they are actually defined at the start.

```
      $item1 = $_SESSION['item1'];
  $item2 = $_SESSION['item2'];
  $item3 = $_SESSION['item3'];
  $item4 = $_SESSION['item4'];
  $item5 = $_SESSION['item5'];
```

Calling my function:

```
ValidateCart($item1, 'item1_name', 'item1_size', 'item1_price', 'item1_url');
```

My Function:

```
      function ValidateCart($item, $itemname, $itemsize, $itemprice, $itemurl)
  {
      $arr = array($item1, $item2, $item3, $item4, $item5);
      if (in_array($item, $arr)) {
        echo '<br><hr>';
        echo $_SESSION[$itemname]; echo '<br>';
        echo $_SESSION[$itemsize]; echo '<br>';
        echo '€ '; echo $_SESSION[$itemprice]; echo '<br><br>';
        $itemurl1 = $_SESSION[$itemurl];
        $itemurl2 = str_replace('url(', 'http://vintagefairytale.esy.es/', $itemurl1);
        $itemurl3 = str_replace(')', '', $itemurl2);

        echo '<img src='; echo $itemurl3; echo '></img>';
        echo '<hr>';
      }
  }
```

Basically, in my `ValidateCart()` I'm making an array with all the possible items, and if an item is matching my array, it will continue. However, it doesn't.

If I change `if (in_array($item, $arr))` to  `if (in_array($item1, $arr))`
it'll work but that's not what I'm trying to achieve.

I need it to work in a function, but to me it doesn't make sense when I call the function with the fit arguments, it won't show. But if I'd do my check inside my function, it works. Hence losing the point of using a function.

---

### SOLVED

The problem was that my $item1 $item2 $item3... wont be used in the scope, not sure why but that was the issue. Calling the sessions inside my function has solved it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `$arr = array($item1, $item2, $item3, $item4, $item5);` all items excluding item1 are out of the function scope.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. But I don't understand why you extract your items from the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you use $arr outside the function and used in function as argument.

```
$arr = array($item1, $item2, $item3, $item4, $item5);
  function ValidateCart($item, $itemname, $itemsize, $itemprice, $itemurl, $arr)
  {

      if (in_array($item, $arr)) {
        echo '<br><hr>';
        echo $_SESSION[$itemname]; echo '<br>';
        echo $_SESSION[$itemsize]; echo '<br>';
        echo '€ '; echo $_SESSION[$itemprice]; echo '<br><br>';
        $itemurl1 = $_SESSION[$itemurl];
        $itemurl2 = str_replace('url(', 'http://vintagefairytale.esy.es/', $itemurl1);
        $itemurl3 = str_replace(')', '', $itemurl2);

        echo '<img src='; echo $itemurl3; echo '></img>';
        echo '<hr>';
      }
  }
```

Comment: I took it outside the function but doesn't help. But yeah better to keep it out.

Comment: you are saying that when you are change $item to $item1 it working because $item doesnt match the array thats why its not working double check the scenario which you are doing

Answer (score 0):

```
function ValidateCart($item, $itemname, $itemsize, $itemprice, $itemurl) {
    $arr = array($_SESSION['item1'], $_SESSION['item2'], $_SESSION['item3'], $_SESSION['item4'], $_SESSION['item5']);
    if (in_array($item, $arr)) {
        echo '<br><hr>';
        echo $_SESSION[$itemname]; echo '<br>';
        echo $_SESSION[$itemsize]; echo '<br>';
        echo '€ '; echo $_SESSION[$itemprice]; echo '<br><br>';
        $itemurl1 = $_SESSION[$itemurl];
        $itemurl2 = str_replace('url(', 'http://vintagefairytale.esy.es/', $itemurl1);
        $itemurl3 = str_replace(')', '', $itemurl2);

        echo '<img src='; echo $itemurl3; echo '></img>';
        echo '<hr>';
      }
  }
```

Your $item1 etc. are out of scope for the function.

Comment: Yup this was it. Thanks a lot. Question though, Why would my function not be able to get the $item1 $item2.... as it is declared above + outside the function? Anyways thanks for the solve!

Comment: $_SESSION is a super global in PHP: http://php.net/manual/de/language.variables.superglobals.php
They can be reached everywhere.
Other variables have to be injected into the function as parameter.

Comment: If you work with classes, you can reach variables which are not in your function scope with $this->item1